# KDE on LTS 18.04 - Cannot Upgrade or 'sudo apt --fix-broken install'

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, kde, upgrade

https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067430/apt-fix-broken-install-does-not-work-package-manager-broken-after-installing
https://askubuntu.com/questions/899497/cannot-fix-broken-packages-apt-get-f-install-doesnt-work

I cannot install anything or upgrade my system. I tried using solutions in the various other answers linked above, but they did not work. I tried to purge the package `libkf5auth-dev`, but it was a dependency of `libkf5configwidgets-dev` and `libkf5configwidgets-dev` is a dependency of many other packages of my system. I am running KDE Neon based on 18.04 LTS, but I never had any sort of issues with aptitude before this.

When i run `sudo apt upgrade`, it gives me this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkf5auth-dev : Depends: libkf5auth5 (= 5.52.0+p18.04+git20181118.0151-0) but 5.52.0+p18.04+git20181130.1300-0 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, it gives me this output:  https://pastebin.com/5DSJKV0S

---

Running `apt-cache policy libkf5auth5 libkf5auth-dev libkf5configwidgets-dev` gives me this output: https://pastebin.com/QuX1gYa8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pastebin says (at the bottom):

```
[...] trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5Auth/KF5AuthToolsTargets-debian.cmake', which is also in package libkf5auth-bin-dev:amd64 5.52.0+p18.04+git20181118.0151-0"
```

This appears to be your direct problem.

The wider problem is you're using one day old git packages, unless you really know what you're doing that's a bad idea.

`sudo apt purge libkf5auth-bin-dev:amd64`

or if that fails then use dpkg:

`sudo dpkg --force-all --remove libkf5auth-bin-dev`

and then you should be able to do the upgrade. **Caution:** dpkg will remove a package when you "force" it even when that hoses your system and leaves it unusable; take care!

`sudo apt install libkf5auth-dev`

But note that as you're installing recently developed packages they may have bugs, including bugs in the packaging itself, such as unsolvable dependency issues that `apt` simply can't resolve consistently. It may not be possible to install those packages with apt.

Comment: I tried that; it did not work. I am unsure what you mean by day old git packages. Also, running `sudo apt purge libkf5auth-bin-dev:amd64` gives me the same output as always https://pastebin.com/LVgWdktW

Comment: You're installing packages that came from git 2 days ago, they're in active development, they're likely to have problems (eg dependencies are wrong). Have you tried removing like `sudo dpkg --force-all --remove libkf5auth-bin-dev`? Note that it may not be possible to install the 30th November 2018 packages and have apt consider your system consistent if the package internal dependency info is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, that fixed! I tried `sudo apt-get --force-yes purge libkf5auth-bin-dev` before, but it did not work and complained about the same dependency issue (depends on package x-`0131`, but x-`1300` is installed)